# Making a seperate table class without borders

Tags: html, css, wordpress, border, css-tables

I'm working on a website with a lot of content, and I have some tables that are styled like this in CSS:

```
table {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 17px;
  width: 75%;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-spacing: 2px;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-color: grey;
 }
```

Now, I'm trying to make some tables that don't have a border at all (so they are just there for formatting). But I can't do it.

I've tried making new classes like this in css:

```
table.noborder td th {border:0;}
```

But when I make a table with the class, it wont work.

I'm using Wordpress, could it be that there are conflicting css or something? I just dont get it. I need a way to do this without having to change all the tables on my site, cause that would be much work.

Comment: Questions like these are not well received here. It is understood that you are new in the field, but research a bit more before you give up and ask a question here.

Comment: Sorry. Where can I ask these newbie questions then? I've been trying this for the past two hours now.

Comment: A simple html css course will do the work for you. Try this course for free in [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/web). Once you complete this course I am sure you will be able to find the answer. After that if you are interested, there are more advanced courses that will assist you even further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nobody will kill you.

It seems, You need to check your HTML markup first.
If you have a TH-tag within a TD-tag, then there's a problem.
That is, what your style is looking for.

TH is used to outline the table header cells, TD for ordinary cells.
Currently, your style would only work for TH-tags that are placed within TD-tags. This will never work.

You have to treat your TDs and THs separately.
So, your CSS should look like this:

```
table.noborder th, table.noborder td {border:0;}
```

Don't forget to assign the noborder-class to your HTML-Tables.
You can also shorten your style sheets:

```
border: <width> <style> <color>;
```

Best regards,
Heiko

Comment: Yes!!! thank you. I guess this is the problem when you learn html just by doing and not learning - you get the simplest of things wrong. Thanks very much.